# VerifyError: Error #1053: Illegal override of addEventListener

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, air, adobe, flash-builder

I'm getting the following error:

```
VerifyError: Error #1053: Illegal override of addEventListener in    
some.path.to.my.CustomObject
```

this usually occurs when trying to load an swf/swc when the versions are different, but it's usually with a custom library, not a flash method like `addEventListener`. My libraries are at the same AIR SDK 3.8 revision, and the top level application has the same version. I was originally using 3.4, but upgraded to 3.8 thinking it might help, but it didn't. I also updated flash player to 11.8, no difference.

The `CustomObject` it's complaining about has no `addEventListener` override in it's class or any base class. The base classes are custom also, they are not derived from flash classes. I'm using Flash Builder 4.7.

I'm unable to compile, and have no idea how to resolve this issue, help is appreciated.

Comment: If the answers below don't help, try showing us the code...

Comment: Thanks Sunil. One of the answers below really helped, the solution is embedded in the comments, it was a [Bindable] tag in the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the package name of the Custom Object, and any methods involved. If the same error persists as an error with the original namespace then you have pre-complied code in your libraries that needs to be removed. You would have to recreate the SWCs potentially. (I am still unsure what libraries you are importing, be careful that you aren't accidentally importing Libraries in your publish settings)

One possibility is that you aren't importing the correct objects by accident: for example class this.package.here.BouncingBall but in fact are importing fl.events.animations.BouncingBall instead.

Comment: In Flash Builder, I'm assuming recreating the swc's is through Project->Clean... I've also removed them manually from the build path. CustomObject has no code in it, except for the Base Class. When I remove the Base Class, the problem goes away - but when I make the Base Class empty, the problem still exists, making me think it's a problem with the Base Class co-existing - but a search doesn't seem to locate another.

Comment: Ok, what solved it is there was a [Bindable] in the parent class and child class, when removing [Bindable] from the parent class, it worked fine?

Comment: I think I've seen this before, but it has been a couple years. Outside of convenience I recommend staying away from [bindable]. Without testing, I suspect one could get this error whenever one uses [bindable] on the same property for a super and subclass. Does this fit your findings?

Comment: Yes - correct. Sorry, just saw your comment, sorry for the delay in responding.

Answer (score 1):

This may help.When you load the external swf and it may contains some conflict class definition with the parent swf, so you may use different domain for the loaded child swf.

```
var appDomainA:ApplicationDomain = new ApplicationDomain(); 

var contextA:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, appDomainA); 
var loaderA:Loader = new Loader(); 
loaderA.load(new URLRequest("application2.swf"), contextA);//application2.swf is you external swf
```

This code and examples could be found in this page [application domain](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSd75bf4610ec9e22f43855da312214da1d8f-8000.html)

Comment: I only have one swf - I'm not loading external swf's. I have two libraries which are part of the build path.

Comment: This solution is more universal than accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found another condition of this - in a base class, sometimes accessing a local variable in the base class through a getter will cause this issue. It seems random, it doesn't always occur.

So instead of

```
protected var __someVar:int;

public function get someVar():int{
  return __someVar;
}

public function addOneToSomeVar():int{
  return someVar + 1; //using local getter - caused VerifyError #1035
}
```

do

```
protected var __someVar:int;

public function get someVar():int{
  return __someVar;
}

public function addOneToSomeVar():int{
  return __someVar + 1; //using local variable
}
```

This isn't always consistent. I was using other getter functions without issues.